# How to extends CBehavior when using massLogout

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii-events

I have made a file `applicationBehavior.php` which are in the component folder, like this :

```
<?php
class applicationBehavior extends CBehavior
{

    public function events() 
    {
        return array(   
            'onBeginRequest'=>'massLogout',         
        );
    }

    public function massLogout()
    {
        $owner = $this->getOwner();
        if($owner->getGlobalState('massLogout') && ($owner->user->name!=='bertho'))
        {                  
            $owner->user->clearStates();
            $owner->catchAllRequest=array('maintenance','view'=>'index');                       
        }
    }
}
```

And I have already registered in the `config/main.php` :

```
'behaviors'=>array(
    'class'=>'application.components.applicationBehavior',
),
```

would I use to do the settings on the application. If I run the controller to disable my application (`Maintenance mode`) would then call in a way :

```
public function actionTurnoff()    
{ 
     Yii::app()->setGlobalState('massLogout',true);
     $this->render('turnoff');
}
```

All users will stop automatically, unless the user that I use the username: `bertho`.

The problem is now when I (username: `bertho`) log out, then I will `lose control` **to get into my application back**.

How should I create a code that if a normal user (`without login`) are not affected by this behavior?

I have tried to examine the conditions :

```
$user = $owner->user->name;
```

and then :

```
if($user!='Guest'){
    if($owner->getGlobalState('massLogout') && $user=='bertho'){
        $owner->user->clearStates();
        $owner->catchAllRequest=array('maintenance','view'=>'index');
    }
}
```

But it always error : `session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed`.

What should I do?